# iOS Ad Hoc Distribution loads but doesn't open

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I've a problem with an ad hoc distribution of an app that is driving me crazy.
I've realized an app for a customer and I would like to let him make some test on it.

For this purpose I created an ah hoc distribution (an .ipa file) and I sent it to him.
He tells me that he can put the app on its device but once tapped, the app loads endlessly without opening and without alert.

I added the device to the portal as I added mine: if I try to put the app on my iPad the app works perfectly.

Is it possible that the problem is that my customer's iPad has iOS 7 whereas my iPad has iOS 6? The app has been developed with SDK 6.1.
I can't find any similar case on internet (maybe I'm not using the right words 'cause I don't speak a perfect English..)

***EDIT***: my customer still gave me the wrong UDID! He changed the iPad but didn't told me although I asked him twice!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried run your's app on IOS 7 emulator?

Comment: Did you send to him the certificates with which the app was signed ?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I'm using xCode 4.6.3 and don't have iOS 7 simulator. I installed it but found that old apps didn't work so I downgraded. I'm trying to find an iPad with iOS 7 to make some test..

Comment: @Miwi, you can install ios 6 sdk on xCode 5.0, just copy it from your's existing xCode and then add it after installation of xCode 5.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. This solved it:

Open Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Select your account > hit View Details > Click the refresh button in the lower left corner

Then create your ipa again.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred to me a month ago. We have tried to ad hoc distribute the app through iTunes and TestFlightApp. but the same thing happened. We could n't understand the problem. If the issue is with provisioning profile or with certificate, iTunes shows an error while pushing the app. But it did nt happen.

The issue is with the Device identifier (UDID). The UDID sent to us was queried by an external app and sent to us. Later, when we got the correct UDID from the iTunes, it was successfully installed. So, the problem might be with the right UDID.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution: Add the UDID to the development provisioning profile. Archive the app and select Distribute>Save for enterprise or adhoc deployment. Save the .ipa. Upload both the .ipa and the development provisioning profile in [www.diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com). Sent your customer the link and tell him to install the profile first and then the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check that your provisioning profile allows for all the capabilities that your app is requesting - iCloud,Game Center, ect.,  My provisioning ad hoc profile didn't contain iCloud, my app did, and it froze on 'Loading...' No error message - grr.